# How to Set a Background Image And Make It Responsive in UI5 Application?

Tags: css, sapui5

I am trying to display an image as page background image using CSS. The image is not responsive on mobile device.

I am using the following code to display background image for a particular page in application:

*CSS*

```css
.page2BgImg {
  background-image: url('../img/mainScr.jpg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

*XML*

```xml
<Page class="page2BgImg">
```

I tried the techniques given in [this blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/04/17/sapui5-and-responsive-web-design-rwd/) but it did not help me in getting the desired result. What are the possible ways to get responsive image on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set a background image, the property [`backgroundImage` of either `sap.m.App` or `.Shell`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.App/controlProperties) can be used together with `backgroundDesign="Transparent"` in `sap.m.Page`:

```xml
<AppOrShell backgroundImage="myImageSrc" backgroundOpacity="1">
```

```xml
<Page backgroundDesign="Transparent">
```

No matter which device, the image is always displayed..

- Centered horizontally
- With the [`background-size: cover`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/)

Here is a demo: **https://output.jsbin.com/nocoday**

[image: Demo of sap.m.App background image]